# How to display large data over a full screen image slider?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, layout, design-patterns, design

On my website www.goo.gl/uompd I have a full screen image slider which works just fine (the images are from screenshots of other websites I have done). On the slider I want to put 4 text boxes, a marquee (right to left vertical news scroll) that scrolls at the top of the page and a 4 X 4 image grid.

As shown on the homepage, all these elements are there. But my concern is that the amount of textboxes is overshadowing the beauty of the image sliding on the background.

Can someone please give me ideas on how I can represent so much data on this full screen image slider?

Comment: The combination of scrolling, fading and tilting makes me feel rather seasick! Could you clarify the purpose of the page/site? Is it to showcase your work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the underlying problem is that all the visual elements are fighting for the user's attention (lots of movement/animation). You should perhaps compile a prioritised ranking of all the information you want to convey to the user, and structure your design around that. At the moment it is unclear what is more important (the marquee, the screenshots, the text on the left?).

If this is a portfolio site, perhaps consider looking at other portfolio sites online, and get a feel for how they are usually structured. Once you have a solid structure, you can start playing with the representation/design.

I realize that this is maybe not the answer that you were looking for, but I hope it points you in the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually what in a case whereby all these elements are important. Thank you.